# Validating Integer in C

Tags: c, validation, input, integer, validating

I am creating a program in C where i have to accept an integer to continue.I read some questions to use the following code but my program just goes into infinite loop soon after entering any character.Please help me

```
    int tnum,scancheck;
printf("Enter the number of teams(Maximum 4)\n");
scancheck = scanf("%d",&tnum);
while(scancheck != 1)
{
    printf("ERROR: Please enter numbers only\n\n");
    printf("Enter the number of teams(Maximum 4)\n");
    scancheck = scanf("%d",&tnum);  
}
```

I used Kirilenko's method but my program goes into infinite loop on entering a special character such as **l=**

**EDIT**
PROBLEM HAS BEEN SOLVED.Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to clean `stdin` between your calls to `scanf`. Otherwise the behaviour of `scanf` with an invalid input is to put back the character on the stream. Then, it go to an infinite loop where you read the same wrong character every iteration.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void clean_stdin(void) {
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
        ;
}

/* ... */

int ret;
int n;

do {
   ret = scanf("%d", &n);
   clean_stdin();
} while (ret != 1);
```

Comment: can you tell me what stdin is?

Comment: It is the input stream (read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_.28stdin.29)).

Comment: Thanks now i know about it.Thanks a lot

Comment: I am using fflush(stdin); now
Is there anything wrong with it

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is a very bad idea: use `fflush` on an input stream (such as `stdin`) is an undefined behavior. For example, the behavior of GNU in that case is to do nothing.

Comment: Thanks.. one last question, where do you gather such knowledge.I mean i am learning c for some time i don't think i will never know this kind of stuff

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to get an input from the user, get the line and analyze it.

```
char   line[1024];
char * err = NULL;
int    num;

while( err == NULL || *err )
{
   fgets( stdin, line );
   num = strtol( line, &err, 10 );
}
```

Until it satisfy the requirement.

Comment: Rather than only post a block of code, please *explain* why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.

Answer (score -2):

Scanf puts the character back on the stdin stream if the input is invalid. Since, we are not clearing the stdin stream, it is going towards an infinite loop.

Try writing this below your scanf statement

```
fflush(stdin);
```

Comment: It worked for me!!Thanks a lot bro.One of the fastest helping community here

Comment: As @Kirilenko already pointed, flushing stdin is undefined behaviour. You should use getchar or scanf("%*c") to manually empty the buffer.

Comment: Yea..I am using Kirilenko's method.Anyway, thanks for your advise

Comment: Agreed. I was just trying giving a different solution than what was already given. :)